# Keeping nested columns a PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have a dataframe `df` with the following schema:

```
 |-- a: decimal(10,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- b: decimal(10,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- c: decimal(10,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- d: decimal(10,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- array_a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a2: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- array_b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- b1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b2: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b3: string (nullable = true)
  |-- e: decimal(10,2) (nullable = true)
  |-- f: decimal(10,2) (nullable = true)
  |-- g: decimal(10,2) (nullable = true)
```

How do you keep the elements of `array_a` when exploding out `array_b`? This code doesn't seem to keep `array_a`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer
cols = df.columns
df_a = df.select(*cols, explode_outer("array_a")).select(*cols, "col.*")
cols_a = df_a.columns
cols.extend(cols_a)
df_b = df.select(*cols, explode_outer("array_b")).select(*cols, "col.*")
```

Comment: Can you explain your use case here?

Comment: @DKNY: Some of the nested fields in array_A are needed to filter the data for array_B and other fields.

Comment: Can you share some sample input and output datasets ? It will be easier for me to understand your requirement in a better way!